# JPA - How to add a reference/foreign key to an item within an ElementCollection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assume the following data model:

1. a pet owner has a pet
2. a pet can perform many tricks
3. a pet owner can participate in a show where his pet can only perform his best trick

The association is shown below. Note that *"tricks"* are a set of strings marked with `@ElementCollection` since in this example it doesn't make sense to manage a trick as a separate entity (We only care about the name of the trick):

```
@Entity
class PetOwner {
    @Id String name;
    @OneToOne Pet pet;
}

@Entity
class Pet {
    @Id String name;
    @ElementCollection Set<String> tricks;
}

@Entity
class PetShowApplicant {
    @Id Integer showId;
    @ManyToOne PetOwner owner;

    //....//

    //what goes here
    String trickToPerform;
}
```

I would like to associate `PetShowApplicant.trickToPerform` to `owner.pet.tricks` to ensure that it references the join table "pet_tricks" created by `@ElementCollection` -  Is this possible? Thanks for your time

Comment: It's better to create an entity for tricks now

Comment: Hi. If I were to create an entity for tricks, how can I reference AND validate from PetShowApplicant? I will want to make sure my Trick belongs to the correct owner

Comment: Then create a PetTrickOwner entity